# Add Animation/Transition to Element When Removed From DOM

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, css-animations

I have a React component for an Error Message element `ErrorMessage` that either returns a div element with child elements or returns `null` so it gets removed from the DOM.

I was curious if there was a way with CSS/React to animate this element as it gets removed from the DOM? I can animate when it renders fine.

Here is a [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wymlm9l60k) to test it.

Here is my SASS

```
.ErrorMessages {
  background: #ee4900;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0.8em 1em;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-name: fadeInUp;
}

.ErrorMessages--Centered {
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-right: 70px;
  padding-left: 70px;
}

.ErrorMessages--fadeOut {
  animation-name: fadeOutDown;
}

@keyframes fadeOutDown {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
    max-height: 72px;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    max-height: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, 50px, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes fadeInUp {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    max-height: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, 50px, 0);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Below is my ErrorMessage component

```
import React from "react";

const ErrorMessage = props => {
  let err = props.show ? (
    <div className="ErrorMessages ErrorMessages--Centered">
      <h4>{props.errorHeader}</h4>
      <p>{props.errorMessage}</p>
    </div>
  ) : null;
  return err;
};

export default ErrorMessage;
```

Which renders in the DOM as

```
<div class="ErrorMessages ErrorMessages--Centered"></div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `setTimeout` and raise an animation flag when `props.show` changes. Something like this:

```
const ErrorMessage = props => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(props.show);
  const [hide, setHide] = useState(!props.show);
  const timeoutRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.show) {
      setShow(true);
      setHide(false);
      clearTimeout(timeoutRef.current);
    }
    else {
      setShow(false);
      timeoutRef.current = setTimeout(() => setHide(true), props.delay || 1000);
    }
  }, [props.show]);

  /* unmount cleanup */
  useEffect(() => () => clearTimeout(timeoutRef.current), []);

  let err = !hide ? (
    <div className={'ErrorMessages ErrorMessages--Centered' + (show ? '' : ' ErrorMessages--fadeOut')}>
      <h4>{props.errorHeader}</h4>
      <p>{props.errorMessage}</p>
    </div>
  ) : null;
  return err;
};
```

Comment: That's perfect, thank you! Works like a charm, didn't think about using a timeout!

Answer (score 3):

You won't be able to animate it without delaying the component unmounting - otherwise the component technically isn't there anymore and therefore you can't add any animation/transition on its leave.

Personally I think that react-transition-group handles the animating very well.

https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group

Then you could use something along the lines of:

```
<TransitionGroup>
    {this.state.showError && 
    <CSSTransition className='animate-error' timeout={{enter: 500, exit: 500}}>
        <ErrorMesage ... />
    </CSSTransition>
    }
</TransitionGroup>
```

and control the states as follow:

```
.animate-error-enter .ErrorMessages.ErrorMessages--Centered { 
    the styles for the initial state of your animation/transition before it enters
}

.animate-error-enter-done .ErrorMessages.ErrorMessages--Centered { 
    the styles you animate to on enter 
}

.animate-error-exit .ErrorMessages.ErrorMessage--Centered { 
    the styles you animate to on exit in order to hide the component 
}
```

The timeout enter and timeout exit should be equal to your animation/transition duration for enter-done and exit.